# Search highlighting (hlsearch) not working in vim

Tags: vim

I have a problem with search highlighting in vim. I have used it before but currently it does not work at all.

- I have entered `:set hlsearch`, which is also in my .vimrc file.
- I have entered `:set hlsearch?` and the result is `hlsearch`, indicating that I have successfully turned the option on. (right?)
- I am running vim and not vi, so that is not the problem.
- I have searched around but only found people asking about turning OFF search highlighting.

I would appreciate any input as this has been driving me nuts. Thanks!

Edit: highlighting also doesn't work for spellcheck, so evidently it's something global about highlighting.

Comment: Try running `vim -u NONE` and test if it works like that.

Comment: @Birei: No, still nothing. Thank you, though.

Comment: was your search pattern found? :) what is the output of `:hi Search`? is the background color same as your normal bg? (gui or cterm )

Comment: @Kent: here's the output of `:hi Search`: `xxx term=reverse ctermbg=11 guibg=Yellow`. The background color is not the same as the normal background; I've tried changing the normal background. Thanks!

Comment: so you saw the `xxx` highlighted correctly?

Comment: @Kent: No, the `xxx` appears like any other text. I was wondering what it was for, but it sounds like it's supposed to show you what highlighting will look like, from your question.

Comment: Change your colorscheme - it may not set the highlighting color correctly.

Comment: @rein: That did it, rein; thanks! This was driving me crazy.

Comment: It might be a matter of different vi, for example, when using sudo. see this: https://serverfault.com/a/350544/91648

Comment: What does one do if :hi Search produces the xxx correctly highlighted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have problems with multiple highlightings (like search and spell in your case), first check the defined highlightings with

```
:hi
```

If any groups are wrong or off, check your `:colorscheme`, and maybe try another.

In the console, color problems are often related to the number of available colors, a hairy problem. Check with

```
:set t_Co?
```

Another good tool for checking problems with individual syntax items is the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

Comment: although your post did not solve my problem it provided some very useful vi commands, thank you :)